# Dovecot and virtual users issue

Tags: postfix, redhat, email-server, dovecot

Kindly find your help on the below,

I am using Dovecot 2.2.5 with postfix 2.10.2 on RHEL 5.9..

I've a problem that I am using Virtual mailboxes,
I need to set passwords for them.

I always have an error message [ no userdb ].

could you please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: 1. What are you using to set passwords? What have you configured in auth-sql.conf ?

Comment: If you're using virtual mailboxes for your virtual users, what manner of virtual password storage are you going to use? Basically, where is your list of users and where is your list of passwords?

Comment: disable_plaintext_auth = no

mail_location = /var/spool/postfix/vhosts/

passdb {
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}


userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}

Comment: I have virtual users in /var/spool/postfix/vhosts/virtual/domain/

Comment: I have passwords in /etc/dovecot/passwd
 in the following format
 user:{PLAIN}password

Comment: So any errors in maillog or dovecot log when you start dovecot?

Comment: user not found from userdb passwd-file

Comment: This error appears in maillog when I try to login via telnet localhost 110 with a specific user

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [link](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/SimpleVirtualInstall) to create virtual user and password for the dovecot users

Comment: I did it an hour ago .. finally I can login via telnet localhost 110 .. entering username and password and it succeed .. but i can't see messages in the mailbox by list command